# Keep lexer from reading first character in file

Tags: c, lexer

I'm making a lexer in c and I noticed that when reading the test code that the file buffer has a strange character that prints as a space. For some reason the lexer reads it from the buffer and treats it like a space.

test file: `mo on`

output

```
Current character: " ", Length: 6, Pointer: 0
Current character: "m", Length: 6, Pointer: 1
Type:2 {
        Line:   1
        Pos:    0
        Number: 21646720
        Real:   21646720
        String: 'mo'
}

Current character: " ", Length: 6, Pointer: 3
Current character: "o", Length: 6, Pointer: 4
Type:2 {
        Line:   1
        Pos:    0
        Number: 21683576
        Real:   21683576
        String: 'o'
}
```

code

```
static char lexer_look(lexer_t* lexer, size_t ahead) {
    if (lexer->len < lexer->ptr + ahead) {
        error_new(lexer->errors, 0, 0, "The lexer tried to index %d out of bounds %d", lexer->ptr + ahead, lexer->len);
        return;
    }
    return lexer->src[lexer->ptr + ahead];
}

static token_t* next_token(lexer_t* lexer) {
    token_t* token = NULL;

    while (token == NULL && can_adv(lexer, 1)) {
        const char c = lexer_look(lexer, 0);

        if (DEBUG)
            printf("Current character: \"%c\", Length: %d, Pointer: %d\n", lexer_look(lexer, 0), lexer->len, lexer->ptr);

        switch (c) {
        case '\n':
            new_line(lexer);
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            break;
        case '\"':
            token = lexer_str(lexer);
            break;
        case '#':
            lexer_comment(lexer);
            break;
        default:
            if (isalpha(c) || c == '_')
                token = lexer_ident(lexer);
            else if (isspace(c))
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    return token;
}
```

Comment: If your problem is that `lexer_look` returns a weird character, then maybe you should post the code for `lexer_look`?

Comment: changing the C character to type of `static int` worked for some reason; However, I added lexer_look to the original post.

Comment: looks like an off-by-one to me : `if (lexer->len < lexer->ptr + ahead) {` --> `if (lexer->ptr + ahead >= lexer->len ) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c` should be defined as an `int` with a value confined in the range `EOF..UCHAR_MAX` for `isalpha()` and `isspace()` to have a reliable behavior.